# How to get the request object from wcf message?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCf service with Contracts  shown below.

```
[MessageContract]
public class ServiceRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public OrderDetails OrderDetails { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class OrderDetails
{
    [IsLogRequired]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [IsLogRequired]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

[IsLogRequired] is custom Attribute.

We need to get all properties in the request which have "[IsLogRequired]" attribute when the request is received. We want to do it as generic solution so that it can be plugged into all services.

We thought of using "MessageInspector" to do this implementing "IDispatchMessageInspector".

How do i get the actual request object from "System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message" parameter of IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest() method?

Please correct me if i am using a wrong interface or wrong method. Any other solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "[IsLogRequired] is custom property." means a custom attribute...

Simple answer is that there is no solution to transfer custom attributes that are decorating the data contract as you described it.

Data contracts should be pure and not encumbered by business logic. The know how about the what should be done with various fields belongs to a service implementation.

Possible approach could look like this:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private void ProcessOrder(Order order)
    {
        var ra = new AuditMetadataResourceAccess();
        MethodInfo[] fieldsToLog = ra.GetLoggingFields(typeof(OrderDetal));

        if (fieldsToLog.Any())
        {
            var logger = new LogingEngine();
            logger.Log(fieldsToLog, order.OrderDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

You could move this implementation inside message inspector or [operation invoker](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx). Carlos Figueira has extensive description of each WCF extensibility point.

"*How do i get the actual request object from "System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message" parameter of IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest() method?*"

I am assuming you are referring to Web request. WebOperationContext.Current but you need to have ASP.NET Compatibility Mode turned on.